# Only last Input works

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this huge form I'm making and there's an also huge problem with it.

In some "areas". only the last input works.

For example here:

```
[...]
<div class="main_data">
   <span class="info">main data</span><br>
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
   <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Website" required>
   <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" required>
   <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required>
   <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required>
   <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" required>
</div>
[...]
```

Every input appears to be disabled(?) and I can only write on Country.

This also happens on some other areas of the form, for example here:

```
[...]
<div class="detailed_info">
   <span class="info">detailed info</span>
   <input type="text" name="activity_areas" placeholder="Activity Areas" required>
   <input type="text" name="company_valences" placeholder="Description of Company Valences" required>
   <input type="text" name="where_operates" placeholder="Markets / Countries where it operates" required>
   <input type="text" name="where_operates" placeholder="Annual Turnover (Value EUR)" required>
[...]
```

I can only write on Annual Turnover.

I tried switching z-index's to check out if it was something over it but I didn't find anything wrong.

I'll paste the css of only the first part, I belive if I find what's happening on the first one I'll be able to correct the second.

```
.main_data{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    background: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.9);
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
       -moz-border-radius: 30px;
            border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.main_data .info{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Futura-Light-Italic', sans-serif;
}
.main_data input{
    border: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 80%;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Futura', sans-serif;
}
.main_data input:focus{
    border: 0;
}
```

I'm still afraid that it might not have nothing to do with the form so I'll leave you guys a link to the page so can try inspecting some elements if you want.

To bring up the form you click Join the City as One of Us: [link](http://inovlancer.com/projetos/cityoffuture.pt/index.php?p=join)

I'm really needing help as this form must be ready today.

Please ask questions if you don't understand something! I will obviously try to help you helping me.

EDIT: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: This may not solve the issue, but you need to close your `input` elements: `<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />` (Specifically: `/>`)

Comment: @Cerbrus I appreciate the tip. But you're right, it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @MarcAudet sorry I forgot to mention it. Google Chrome

Comment: @White8Tiger My answer is correct, I have checked it.

Comment: The problem appears in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: you have two inputs named `where_operates`

Comment: @Brino although it doesn't have anything to do with the problem, I wasn't even noticing, thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `line-height` on `.oneofus`.

```
.oneofus {
  width: 88%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 1px; /* this is the problem remove it or make it bigger (74px or more) */
}
```

Comment: I changed it to 19px and the problem is still thre. Also the margins got bigger.. I don't even know why.

Comment: @White8Tiger Remove it completely and you will see it working. Im not going to recode the whole thing for you. Yes it will break the layout but that is because this isn't how you use line-height. This is the problem.

Comment: @White8Tiger Thanks, like i said you don't want the line to be `1px`. You will have to move some stuff around to get the same look again but you can do it. If you need help please shorten the code and put it in a JSFiddle and I will give you hand.

Comment: I appreciate the offer but I already worked it around. I got it working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of the inputs to relative..

```
.main_data input {
  position: relative;
}
```